# Bash test - unary operator expected

Tags: bash

I have the following check. I try to call the `isValid` function that takes `2` arguments.

```
if [ $(isValid $road $number) -eq 0 ] ; then
(...)
```

In return I get:

```
[: -eq: unary operator expected
```

In that case I would like to use `[]` over `[[]]`. I escaped arguments with `""` but it didn't work.
What am I missing ?

---

EDIT:

```
function isValid{
    local road_name=$1
    local road_number=$2

    [[ $road_number == "lombard" && $road_number == "10" ]] && return 0
    return 1
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `isValid $road $number` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if [ $(isValid $road $number) -eq 0 ] ; then

This checks if the standard output is equal to 0. Ex.:

```
if [ $(echo 0) -eq 0 ] ; then
```

`echo 0` outputs `0`. Then you check with the `[` command, if the output of the command `echo 0` is equal to `0`. The `[` command returns zero status, if the expression is true. It returns non-zero status, if the expression is false.

You want to check *exit status* of a command. Just:

```
if isValid "$roud" "$number"; then
```

The `if` expression is run, when the *exit status* of a command is zero. You can use `!` command to invert the exit status.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but `$(echo 0)` runs `echo 0` in subshell, so it gives us `0`. Then, shouldn't `$(echo 0) -eq 0` be true ?

Comment: `[ $(echo 0) -eq      0  ]` will return with 0 exit status. It is true. In computers `0` exit status is considered succes, nonzero is failure. It may be confusing at first, but you can get used to it. Ex. `true` command returns with zero status, while `false` returns 1.

Comment: so if `[ $(echo 0) -eq 0 ]` is true. Shouldn't `[ $(isValid $road $number) -eq 0 ]` be `true` as well ?

Comment: No. `isValid` does not output 0. "output" -> what goes to stdanard output with file descriptor `1` of a command. It does not `echo 0` or `printf 0` or similar. The function `isValid` does `return 0`. It set's an exit status. You can check the exit status of a command with `$?`, ex. `out=$(isValid $road $number); ret=$?; echo "isValid outputted $out"; echo "isValid returned: $ret". The command substitution `$( ... )` is expanded with the content of the standard output of a command with trailing empty lines removed.